# Eyeballing bus capacitance

Tags: uart, capacitance, bus

I would like to use single-wire half-duplex UART bus to connect together two STM32 controllers and one ESP32 module. They all will have diodes on TX and share one pull-up. The wiring uses 2m of common 28AWG USB cable. The target speed is 921600 bps, but I am not sure if it is achievable.

I think the pull-up can be calculated the same way as for I2C bus, but it requires bus capacitance for maximum R calculation. I have no idea how to get that other than wire the actual system with chips removed from the boards and measure it, then add input capacitances from datasheets.

Is there a better way to get at least ballpark figure for the setup above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anything that goes via a user-accessible cable I’d use RS-485 and then not have to worry about wire capacitances all that much. I’ve ran 1.5MBit 485 on a 1000 ft shielded 24AWG pair. At short distances it doesn’t even need very careful termination - each of the devices may have say 300 ohms across the pair of there’s only 3 of them.

Comment: In this case the cable is only "accessible" in that the user can see it coming out of one box and disappearing into another. The connectors are inside the enclosures. Here is a little background: the system was originally designed and run great on CANopen bus. Then chip shortage hit and we had to use what was available. New STM32 MCUs did not have CAN and were too small to run CANopen stack anyway. So, we switched to UART. It worked just fine, but then ESP was added to the system and we ended up with multi-drop bus. Just trying to salvage the situation

Comment: Go for cheapest 485 transceivers. They don’t need fancy ESD protection. It’ll work just fine. CANopen is overkill unless you got servo drives or sensors that use it. Bare CAN does not need CANopen and works great as a “value broadcasting” bus. With 485 you’ll need to manage medium access. Fixed schedule timed by one node may be simplest. Node A sends its data. When the packet ends, node B does it. Then node C. All nodes “listen” to know when the predecessor is done.

Comment: A very good guess! We did have 4 third party servo drivers in the system originally. To save the costs we later added that functionality to our own board but kept the protocol. And on UART version we already have single master polling the nodes round-robin, to deal with some application-specific timing issues. Come to think of it, if not for low bitrate the LIN bus would be perfect link layer for this application.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it provides a very nice alternative to the multi-drop UART. In the end we did use RS-485 with minimal changes in software. For the readers looking for an answer to the actual OP question I'd recommend [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/672410/187920) by @Neil_UK

Answer (score 5):

100 pF/metre is a reasonable and conservative ballpark.

1 Mbaud should work over 2 metres easily enough, but you'll feel more comfortable with an oscilloscope for verifying rise times and edge placements.

You might want to have a look at [IEEE-488](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE-488) and see if you can find the physical layer specification.  That covers a bus of up to 20 m of any topology running at that sort of speed, with essentially TTL O/C connections to it. IIRC, it uses Thevnin pullups to about 3.3 V with an effective 200 (ish) ohms resistance.

Comment: "should work easily enough" -- but note that the pullup will have to be pretty low for this, say 470 ohms. Shouldn't be a problem for typical logic drivers and short length cable, but it's not exactly micropower, in case that's a concern.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, I was worried about that too. Maybe I'll have to add buffers or FETs to drive the bus. Or find a way to cap speed requirements

Comment: @Maple Check my edit

Answer (score 1):

> They all will have diodes on TX and share one pull-up.

As an alternative to diodes, you could have a series resistor at each device. This would act as series termination to reduce reflections and limit current in case two devices are trying to drive the bus at once.

Unlike diodes, series resistors provide a stronger and symmetric push-pull drive.

To get best bandwidth out of a cable, the series termination resistors should match the cable impedance, which is 90 ohms for USB cable. However, you can make the resistance higher and it will just result in slightly slower rise & fall times, while limiting the fault current between two active transmitters.

For example 200 ohm series resistors on 200 pF cable capacitance would provide rise/fall time of about 80 ns (10% to 90%). It would limit the current to 3.3V/(2 * 200ohm) = 8 mA if two devices are trying to drive the bus at the same time.

There should still be a weak pull-up that holds the line high when all devices have disabled their output pins.

Comment: As I understand the question, these diodes form a "wired or" on the 1 wire bus and suppess the push pull drive of the always active TX outputs.

Comment: @Jens Yes, but UART prototocol does not take advantage of the wired-or behavior, so I think the slower rise time of pull-up + open-collector is a big disadvantage with no corresponding advantage.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I do not see the "termination" resistor working as expected if connected in the middle (we have 3 devices on the bus).

Comment: @Maple It won't be ideal, especially if the branch lengths are different. You can consider it as two buses originating from the same point. Initial rise voltage is lower because of twice the bus load, and part of the reflections that return back get coupled to the other branch. Reflections are still attenuated more than without any termination, though.